# No puedo obtener 1 objeto de mi base de datos , problema con SQLite y PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mvc, web, sqlite

Estoy haciendo un sistema con un CRUD completo, el unico problema que tengo es que no puedo recuperar 1 objeto de mi base de datos, puedo listar todos los objetos pero no obtener solo 1 , estoy usando MVC y java web.

Aqui les dejo el servlet que ejecuta la busqueda

```
@Override
    public Usuario_DTO_bean mostrarUsuario(String usu) {
        Usuario_DTO_bean usuarioMostrar= new Usuario_DTO_bean(1, "falla", "falla", "falla", 1, "falla", "falla", "falla");
        try {
            String sql="select * from usuario where usuario =?";
            con=Conector.connect();
            PreparedStatement statement;
            statement=con.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1,usu);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
                String usuario = resultSet.getString("usuario");
                String clave = resultSet.getString("clave");
                String permisos=resultSet.getString("permisos");
                int estado=resultSet.getInt("estado");
                String nombre=resultSet.getString("nombre");
                String apellido_p=resultSet.getString("apellido_p");
                String apellido_m=resultSet.getString("apellido_m");
                usuarioMostrar=new Usuario_DTO_bean(id, usuario, clave, permisos, estado, nombre, apellido_p,apellido_m);
            }
            resultSet.close();
            statement.close();
            con.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        return usuarioMostrar;



    }
```

Luego de probar ,creo que el problema esta en esta linea de codigo

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
```

Ya que luego de esta linea no se ejecuta ningun codigo, ni un simple println en consola y salta de frente al return, como si el try detectara un error y saliera del bloque

Con este código en un main ejecuto la función

```
String registro="SI-84";
    Usuario_DTO_bean usuario;
    Usuario_DTO_bo bo=new Usuario_DTO_bo();
    usuario=bo.mostrarUsuario(registro);
    System.out.println(usuario.getId());
    System.out.println(usuario.getUsuario());
```

Deben saber que existe el usuario con registro SI-84 , pero en vez devolverme sus valores me regresa lo siguiente

[image: No son los valores del usuario SI-84]

Comment: *como si el try detectara un error y saliera del bloque*. Pues eso es lo que está pasando, **nunca** dejes un bloque `catch` vacío, al menos pon `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Puedes imprimir el error en el bloque "catch" como comenta Pablo, con eso se puede tener más idea sobre el tipo de problema que presentas.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, tienes razon pero el error mas grande me he dado cuenta es el Prepare Statement el cual arroja un error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ademas del error de no poner una excepción en el catch como me indicaron , el problema estaba en que talvez por usar SQLite no me deja usar PrepareStatement, ya que el error por consola me indicaba un error SQL diciendo que no soportaba el PrapareStatement  con el cual queria usar el tipico "?" para reemplazar los datos.

Ahora en vez de usar PrepareStatement , simplemente use Statement he hice un pequeño  cambio en la sentencia sql, con esto funciona de maravilla :D

```
//Metodo para mostrar 1 solo usuario
    @Override
    public Usuario_DTO_bean mostrarUsuario(String usu) {
        Usuario_DTO_bean usuarioMostrar= new Usuario_DTO_bean(1, "falla", "falla", "falla", 1, "falla", "falla", "falla");
        try {
            String sql="select * from usuario where usuario ='"+usu+"'";
            con=Conector.connect();
            Statement statement;
            statement=con.createStatement();
            //statement.setString(1,usu);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                int id = resultSet.getInt("id");
                String usuario = resultSet.getString("usuario");
                String clave = resultSet.getString("clave");
                String permisos=resultSet.getString("permisos");
                int estado=resultSet.getInt("estado");
                String nombre=resultSet.getString("nombre");
                String apellido_p=resultSet.getString("apellido_p");
                String apellido_m=resultSet.getString("apellido_m");
                usuarioMostrar=new Usuario_DTO_bean(id, usuario, clave, permisos, estado, nombre, apellido_p,apellido_m);
            }
            resultSet.close();
            statement.close();
            con.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return usuarioMostrar;
```

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar te regresan esos valores porque lo estás instanciando en un principio

```
Usuario_DTO_bean usuarioMostrar= new Usuario_DTO_bean(1, "falla", "falla", "falla", 1, "falla", "falla", "falla");
```

Por lo que veo, hasta ahora me parece que está bien el método. Como te dicen tienes que imprimir la excepción algo así:

```
try{
//La lógica
}catch(SQLException ex){
      System.out.println("No se pudo encontrar el usuario " + ex.getMessage());
}
```

Si es que hubiera un error, saber exactamente cuál es el error que te sale para poder ayudarte. 
Saludos

Comment: El error aparte de no poner una excepción en el catch, era porque por lo visto al usar el SQLite no me deja usar el PrepareStatement,  asi que use Statement y funciono bien como indica mi respuesta, gracias :D